# Append string to an exitsting array key? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to append the key from $teasers to the key of the array contained within each $teasers element and then create an associative array that contains the appended keys for its key and the content of the sub array for its content. Following? I hope so, if not here's an example of my desired end product:

This is a simplified version of the multidimensional array I'm working with:

```
$teasers[0]=array('id'     => 4,
                  'title'  => 'How to determine the speed of an african swallow',
                  'content'=> 'Its really quite simple...')

$teasers[1]=array('id'      => 5,
                  'title'   => 'Man alleged to be cereal killer after breakfast',
                  'content' => 'Turns out eating a delicious bowl of froste...')
```

I'm working towards turning it into this:

```
$data Array(
           '/*Key from subarray+$teasers key*/' => '/*content from subarray*/',
           'id0'       => '4',
           'title0'    => 'How to determine the speed of an african swallow',
           'content0'  => 'Its really quite simple...',
           'id1'       => '5',
           'title1'    => 'Man alleged to be cereal killer after breakfast',
           'content1'  => 'Turns out eating a delicious bowl of frosted...')
```

Still not following? I don't blame you. Maybe this will help. I was originally going about it like this until I realized you can't pass a variable into a foreach loop. ):

```
foreach ($teasers as $key => $blogentry) {

    foreach($blogentry as $entrykey => $content){

        //Basically I would like to append $key to the end of $entrykey
        //so that I can essentially access all of the data from one array($data[])

        $data[$entrykey.$key] = $content;
    }
}
```

I'm more than happy to do anything I can to make things more clear or help you help me. Thanks for your time in advance!!

Comment: `I was originally going about it like this until I realized you can't pass a variable into a foreach loop. ):` ???

Comment: your code is working fine "as is"

Comment: Oh man sorry people, IDK what i was doing before that was making it seem like i couldn't pass $key into the next loop. After reading the responses I just copy pasted what I have here and POOF it works. My brain is mush. Im super new to the world of programming and its taking its toll.

Should I delete this post???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code should work. Add `$data = array();` before your loops.